# Cron not running - any symptoms to check?

Tags: cron

I have cron set to run every 3 hours on /admin/config/system/cron (D7's poormanscron). I can run it manually just fine from that page, but over the course multiple days it simply won't run by itself. Nothing in the "Recent Log Messages" (except the "Cron run completed." for the times I manually ran it, aka 3 days ago). Multiple users accessing the site (anon & reg'd), so it should be firing.

Anyway, any obvious places y'all can think of to check what may be going wrong? Worst case I'll just set up a crontab. Website is http://community.habitrpg.com/

Comment: Have you checked the the value of 'cron_safe_threshold' in the variables table? If it is set to 0 that would block the internal cron.

Comment: If you can set up a crontab, set it up. Its more reliable than depending on anonymous/authenticated users traffic.

Comment: @Triskelion alas, is 3600 as expected. I'll just go with system cron as 2-Stroker suggests

Comment: if you can do it, it is always preferable. I shut off the internal cron on all my sites and have found the system cron to be not only more reliable, but more efficient. You can also trigger the cron task from a remote machine. You do not have to issue the wget from the web server.

Comment: I just ran into a similar issue.  On our site the `install_task` system variable had not been correctly set to `done`.  Running `variable_set('install_task', 'done');` allowed Cron to start up as I would expect.